# Must CSRs be generated on the server that will host the SSL certificate?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

Is it necessary to generate the CSR (Certificate Signing Request) on the same machine that will host my web application and SSL certificate?

Comment: Looks like a Server Fault question to me (though I've provided an answer anyway)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No; the CSR includes the hostname or hostnames for which the resulting certificate will be valid, so as long as they are specified at creation time, copying the private key and the certificate produced from the CSR to the machine on which the service is to run will work fine.  Best not to lose the CSR, though, as it can be used to generate a new certificate when one expires.